# How to query array columns in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql

I can't find any good articles about how to query `array columns` in Rails. I came across the need to query an Array column in Rails.

I found from an article teaching how to do basic query [here](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-arrays-in-rails-with-postgresql/).

Let's follow the example in the article where `Book` covers many `subjects` and subjects is stored as an array column:

```
add_column :books, :subjects, :text, array: true, default: []
```

> **Query books that contains a certain subject** - e.g. History

```
Book.where("'history' = ANY (subjects)")
```

> **Query books that contains all listed subjects** - e.g. Finance AND Business AND Accounting

```
Book.where("subjects @> ?", "{Finance,Business,Accounting}")
```

---

I wonder how I can do the following?

> **Query books that contains any of the listed subjects** - e.g. Fiction OR Biography
>
> **Query books that doesn't contain a certain subject** - e.g. NOT Physics
>
> **Query books that doesn't contain ANY of the subjects** - e.g. NOT (Physics OR Chemistry OR Biology)

And is there any `Rails` way of doing the above queries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Usually, [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) are a preferable way of approaching the problem:

   `Book has_many :subjects # or has_one/has_and_belongs_to_many`

   `Subject belongs_to :book # or has_and_belongs_to_many`

   And then just create a table `subjects`, save all your subjects there and you're set up.
2. Your queries:

> Query books that contains any of the listed subjects - e.g. Fiction OR
>   Biography

```
Book.find_by_sql "SELECT * FROM books WHERE 'Fiction' = ANY (subjects) OR 'Biography' = ANY (subjects)"
```

> Query books that doesn't contain a certain subject - e.g. NOT Physics

```
Book.where.not("subjects @> ?", "{Physics}")
```

> Query books that doesn't contain ANY of the subjects - e.g. NOT
>   (Physics OR Chemistry OR Biology)

```
Book.find_by_sql "SELECT * FROM books WHERE books NOT IN (SELECT * FROM books WHERE 'Physics' = ANY (subjects) OR 'Chemistry' = ANY (subjects) OR 'Biology' = ANY (subjects)"
```

Comment: Hmm, I saw that postgres and Rails 4 came out with the array column. I guess sometimes the performance is actually better when storing as array columns? I may ask a new question to see if anyone can evaluate when to use array column and when to use associations

Comment: then why is array column created? I assume it is rails intention to adopt some noSQL approach of storing data? I am no expert in it and would like to learn more, I think if Rails 4 / Postgres decides to implement it, there must be a reason? We can offload this discussion to another thread. => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569511/when-should-i-use-array-columns-v-s-associations-in-rails

Comment: @ChrisYeung Despite the results of the separate question let me know, if this answer was helpful with regards to queries

Comment: Bad advice in the first paragraph - there are valid reasons to store array data in database. If there wasn't a good enough use case for it, the data type wouldn't exist (although I agree in OP's case it *should* be an association). However, +1 for actually providing the solution of how to query the array datatype and answering OP's question.

Answer (score 31):

For,

**Query books that contains any of the listed subjects - e.g. Fiction OR Biography**

```
Book.where("subjects &&  ?", "{Fiction,Biography}")
```

**Query books that doesn't contain a certain subject - e.g. NOT Physics**

```
Book.where("subjects <>  ?", "{Physics}")
```

**Query books that don't contain ANY of the subjects - e.g. NOT (Physics OR Chemistry OR Biology)**

```
Book.where.not("subjects &&  ?", "{Physics,Chemistry,Biology}")
```

You can see the array functions of Postgres for reference.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-array.html

Comment: How would you query this with dynamic subjects?