# Rails 5.2 Controller for Where Array Doesn't Include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model called `hardships` with an array value for the users that have voted to approve that hardship (`:approvals => []` in the `hardship_params`).

I'm trying to create a list of `hardships` on the index page for hardships which any given `current_user` (using devise) has NOT approved.

The array is formed with user ids, so a typical value for `@hardship.approvals` would be `["2", "3"]` if the second and third users had approved it.

I'm having trouble with the logic to call this from the controller.  I've looked at SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441791/how-to-select-where-id-in-array-rails-activerecord-without-exception) but can't glean an answer that works for Rails 5.2 and Postgres.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
@need_approval = Hardship.where.not(approvals.include?(current_user.id.to_s))
```

However, I know that doesn't work because `approvals` isn't a variable and the syntax is all wrong.  Can anyone help me Rails-ify this so it gets the info I need?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

Here's my `hardships` table:

```
  create_table "hardships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "full_name"
    t.date "date"
    t.string "position"
    t.string "branch"
    t.string "email_non_toca"
    t.string "mobile"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "zip"
    t.string "bank_name"
    t.string "bank_phone"
    t.string "bank_address"
    t.date "start_date"
    t.boolean "accident", default: false
    t.boolean "catastrophe", default: false
    t.boolean "counseling", default: false
    t.boolean "family_emergency", default: false
    t.boolean "health", default: false
    t.boolean "memorial", default: false
    t.boolean "other_hardship", default: false
    t.string "other_hardship_description"
    t.decimal "requested_amount"
    t.text "hardship_description"
    t.decimal "self_fund"
    t.string "intent_signature"
    t.date "intent_signature_date"
    t.string "release_signature"
    t.date "release_signature_date"
    t.string "status", default: "Application Started"
    t.string "final_decision", default: "Not Decided"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "returned", default: false
    t.text "approvals", default: [], array: true
    t.text "rejections", default: [], array: true
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_hardships_on_user_id"
  end
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an association between `Hardship` and `User`?

Comment: @jvillian Because a user can either approve, reject, or request to modify a `hardship` (as well as two other types of applications...`scholarship` and `charity`) and that seemed like a not DRY amount of join tables to create.

Comment: @Liz does `approvals` from here `@hardship.approvals` column or table ?

Comment: @jvillian I added my hardships schema to the OP.

Comment: Hang on @Liz, I'm working on it...

Comment: Like the other comments said, you should be using a join table for this. But if you decide not to, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31569083/2697183 (which also recommends a join table)

Comment: @Liz - Sorry that took a while. Extended answer, below. IMO, quite DRY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I think I would be tempted to create a `ApplicationAction` model. Something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: application_actions
#
#  id               :bigint           not null, primary key
#  user_id          :integer
#  application_type :string
#  application_id   :integer
#  action           :integer
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#

class ApplicationAction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :application, polymorphic: true

  enum action: {
    approved:             0,
    rejected:             1,
    requested_to_modify:  2
  }  
end
```

Then, in your `User` model, do something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :application_actions

  %i(
    approved
    rejected
    requested_to_modify
  ).each do |action_sym|
    %w(
      hardship
      scholarship
      charity
    ).each do |application_type|

      # Create the associations: 
      #   - hardship_applications
      #   - scholarship_applications
      #   - charity_applications
      has_many "#{application_type}_applications".to_sym,
        -> { distinct },
        through:      :application_actions,
        source:       :application,
        source_type:  application_type.camelize

      # Define the methods:
      #   - approved_application_actions
      #   - rejected_application_actions
      #   - requested_to_modify_application_actions
      define_method("#{action_sym}_application_actions") do 
        application_actions.send(action_sym)
      end

      # Define the methods:
      #   - approved_hardship_applications
      #   - rejected_hardship_applications
      #   - requested_to_modify_hardship_applications
      #   - approved_scholarship_applications
      #   - rejected_scholarship_applications
      #   - requested_to_modify_scholarship_applications
      #   - approved_charity_applications
      #   - rejected_charity_applications
      #   - requested_to_modify_charity_applications
      define_method("#{action_sym}_#{application_type}_applications") do 
        send("#{application_type}_applications").
          joins(:application_actions).
          where(
            application_actions: {
              action: ApplicationAction.actions[action_sym]
            }
          )
      end

      # Define the methods:
      #   - hardship_applications_not_approved
      #   - hardship_applications_not_rejected
      #   - hardship_applications_not_requested_to_modify
      #   - scholarship_applications_not_approved
      #   - scholarship_applications_not_rejected
      #   - scholarship_applications_not_requested_to_modify
      #   - charity_applications_not_approved
      #   - charity_applications_not_rejected
      #   - charity_applications_not_requested_to_modify
      define_method("#{application_type}_applications_not_#{action_sym}") do 
        application_type.
          camelize.
          constantize.
          where.
          not(id: send("#{action_sym}_#{application_type}_applications"))
      end

    end
  end

end
```

And, in your `Hardship` model, do something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: hardships
#
#  id               :bigint           not null, primary key
#  application_type :integer          default(NULL)
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#

class Hardship < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :application_actions, as: :application

  enum application_type: {
    accident:           0,
    catastrophe:        1,
    counseling:         2,
    family_emergency:   3,
    health:             4,
    memorial:           5,
    other_hardship:     6
  }
end
```

Then, if I run that through a quick RSpec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Hardship Applications' do
  before(:each) do 
    @user_1               = User.create!
    @user_2               = User.create!
    @hardship_1           = Hardship.create!
    @user_1.
      application_actions.
      create!(application: @hardship_1).
      approved!
    @user_2.
      application_actions.
      create!(application: @hardship_1).
      rejected!
  end
  it "user_1 approved_hardship_applications to include hardship_1" do 
    expect(@user_1.approved_hardship_applications).to include(@hardship_1)
  end
  it "user_1 hardship_applications_not_approved NOT to include hardship_1" do 
    expect(@user_1.hardship_applications_not_approved).not_to include(@hardship_1)
  end
  it "user_1 rejected_hardship_applications NOT to include hardship_1" do 
    expect(@user_1.rejected_hardship_applications).not_to include(@hardship_1)
  end
  it "user_2 approved_hardship_applications NOT to include hardship_1" do 
    expect(@user_2.approved_hardship_applications).not_to include(@hardship_1)
  end
  it "user_2 hardship_applications_not_approved to include hardship_1" do
    expect(@user_2.hardship_applications_not_approved).to include(@hardship_1)
  end
  it "user_2 rejected_hardship_applications to include hardship_1" do 
    expect(@user_2.rejected_hardship_applications).to include(@hardship_1)
  end
end
```

I get...

```
Hardship Applications
  user_1 approved_hardship_applications to include hardship_1
  user_1 hardship_applications_not_approved NOT to include hardship_1
  user_1 rejected_hardship_applications NOT to include hardship_1
  user_2 approved_hardship_applications NOT to include hardship_1
  user_2 hardship_applications_not_approved to include hardship_1
  user_2 rejected_hardship_applications to include hardship_1

Finished in 0.13431 seconds (files took 0.90021 seconds to load)
6 examples, 0 failures
```

So, you can do:

```
@need_approval = current_user.hardship_applications_not_approved
```

instead of:

```
@need_approval = Hardship.where.not(approvals.include?(current_user.id.to_s))
```

Also you'll note that in the `Hardship` model, I made all your application types into an `enum`. This will cut down on empty fields (assuming a `Hardship` application can be of only one application type).

There appear to be other opportunities for reducing redundancy. For instance, you could create `PhysicalAddress`, `PhoneNumber`, and `EmailAddress` models and associate these with each type of application. You could also create your application `status` to an `enum` and default it to `application_started`. Same with `final_decision`.

Comment: This is awesome and incredibly detailed!  It took me a while to understand it all, but truly fantastic.  Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing, so glad it helped! LMK if you have any additional questions about this.